# Удаленное подключение к Raspberry Pi 2 из другой сети

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, sftp

Купил себе малину. Все настроил - все работает ! Но есть проблема. На роутере настроил перенаправление с моего внешнего IP на адрес малины. Сайт открывается, все как положено. Но при попытке подключится с помощью внешнего IP через Putty или FileZill'y - ошибка.

Знает ли кто решение этой проблемы ?

Comment: Опишите ваше "перенаправление" и как вы его сделали. Его явно недостаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у вас не настроена переадресация портов?
На моем роутере (ASUS) это делается Доп. настройки -> Интернет -> Переадресация портов 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Локальный порт по-умолчанию 22 (SSH).

**UPDATE**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь 2 записи на 10201 порте весит сервер, а на 10202 SSH. Значит при доступе [http://вне.шни.йi.p:10201/](http://%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5.%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8.%D0%B9i.p:10201/) будет открываться сайт, а ssh://вне.шни.йi.p:10202/ будет доступ к SSH

Comment: Вот скриншот настроек http://prntscr.com/alix0z Как я понял нужно заменить порт на 22 ?

Comment: Заменил порт на 22 - успешно подключился. Но теперь по моему ip сайт не отрывается

Comment: Вы не замените на 22 порт а добавьте еще один порт в проброску. То есть записей должно быть две. См. обновление в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил тем, что в настройках виртуального сервера в панели роутера выставил внешний и внутренний порты в диапазоне от 22 до 80.

Comment: нужно не диапазон, а просто два правила. Одно для 22, другое для 80. Так будет правильнее.